# Possessive/Genitive form of „man“

Tags: grammar

Consider the english sentence: “You should change your password frequently” (or “One should change one's password frequently.”)

What word would be used to translate *your* above? I know that *man* would be used to translate *you*, but I don't know what the possessive form of *man* would be.

Can you repeat *man* but add an *-s* to make it possessive? (e.g., „Man soll häufig mans Kennwort ändern.“) Or is there some other word that can be used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you simply use *sein* (=his):

> Man soll sein Passwort regelmäßig ändern.

Comment: Since you rolled back, I’ll have to note here that _regelmäßig_ doesn’t mean the same as _frequently_.

Comment: That's fine. I was merely shooting for an idiomatic expression.